# Como embaralhar caracteres de uma String em Java de forma aleatória?

Tags: java, array, string, random, char

Estou desenvolvendo um programa gerador de passwords. Nele o usuário pode setar a porcentagem de números, letras e caracteres especiais que deseja ter na sua senha, assim como o tamanho da sua senha. Mais adiante eu concateno os números, letras e símbolos e preciso embaralhá-los, de forma a ficar parecido com uma senha (essa foi a melhor solução que encontrei para gerar senhas seguindo este conceito de porcentagem de caracteres).

O problema é que preciso embaralhar um array de caracteres de forma aleatória.

Este array pode ser um array de `char`, ou mesmo uma `String`, o importante é que tenho que imprimir isso na tela de forma embaralhada posteriormente.

Pesquisando um pouco, encontrei a função `shuffle();` da classe `Collecions` e escrevi o seguinte código, que faz justamente o que eu quero:

```
public static String shuffleString(String s) {
    List<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
    String temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        letters.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    System.out.println("");

    Collections.shuffle(letters);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        temp += letters.get(i);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

O problema é que acho este código um pouco "pesado". Penso que deve existir alguma forma mais simples de fazer isto. Também tenho me preocupado sobre a forma em que estes itens são embaralhados, pois preciso de algo aleatório, ou o mais aleatório possível.

Comment: O problema aqui é um tanto quanto a sintaxe do Java. Acho o código demasiado extenso para fazer algo simples. Penso estar fazendo isto de forma errada ou senão, de uma forma pouco eficiente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abusando um pouquinho de regex:

```
public static String shuffle(String s) {
    List<String> letters = Arrays.asList(s.split(""));
    Collections.shuffle(letters);
    StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (String k : letters) {
        t.append(k);
    }
    return t.toString();
}
```

[Veja rodando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/Aky6Gm)

Comment: Perfeito, era justamente isto que precisava. Bem mais limpo do que meu código. Muito grato! :)

Answer (score 6):

Que tal usar Java 8?

```
public static String shuffle(String s) {
    List<Character> letters = s.chars().boxed().map(c -> (char) c.intValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(letters);
    StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    letters.forEach(t::append);
    return t.toString();
}
```

Comment: Estou utilizando o jdk 1.7.0_51, não tenho como testar isto aqui. Saberia me dizer se há alguma solução similar que funciona no 1.7?

Answer (score 4):

Vamos assim então:

```
public static String shuffleString(String s) {
    char[] caracteres = s.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(caracteres));
    Collections.shuffle(lista);
    return lista;

}
```

Comment: O retorno do método é `String`, mas você está retornando `ArrayList<String>`, o que dá erro de compilação. Além disso, o `Arrays.asList` funciona só para arrays de tipos objeto e não para arrays de tipos primitivos.