# Ajuda com palavras embaralhadas

Tags: java, string

Preciso de ajuda em um programa, não faço ideia de como fazer, o enunciado é o seguinte:

"Palavra embaralhada - Implementar um programa que, a partir de um banco de palavras, seleciona aleatoriamente uma palavra, baralha as letras e dá um tempo para o usuário adivinhar a palavra."

Pensei em usar dois vetor de Strings, e um random para eu pegar um índice do vetor principal e colocar no outro para ficar aleatório, porem ele pode gerar um indice repetido.

Comment: Relacionada [Como embaralhar caracteres de uma String em Java de forma aleatória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97940/como-embaralhar-caracteres-de-uma-string-em-java-de-forma-aleat%C3%B3ria?rq=1).

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte implementação:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Embaralhar {

  private final String[] palavras = new String[]{"ACEROLA", "ABACATE", "ABACAXI", "AMEIXA",
    "AMORA", "BANANA", "CAJU", "CAQUI",
    "CARAMBOLA", "CEREJA", "DAMASCO", "FIGO",
    "FRAMBOESA", "GOIABA", "GRAVIOLA", "GROSELHA",
    "JABUTICABA", "JACA", "LARANJA", "MELANCIA",
    "MANGA", "MEXERICA", "MIRTILO", "MORANGO",
    "NECTARINA", "PEQUI", "PITANGA", "KIWI",
    "TAMARINDO", "TANGERINA", "UVA"};

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Embaralhar embaralhar = new Embaralhar();
    TimedScanner scanner = new TimedScanner(System.in);
    String digitada;

    try {
      while (true) {
        String original = embaralhar.escolherPalavraAleatoria().toUpperCase();
        String embaralhada = embaralhar.embaralhar(original);
        System.out.println("A palavra embaralhada é: " + embaralhada);

        digitada = scanner.nextLine(15000);

        if (digitada == null) {
          System.out.println("Você levou mais de 15 segundos para inserir uma resposta. Seja mais rápido da próxima vez.");
        } else if (digitada.toUpperCase().equals("SAIR")) {
          System.out.println("Você escolheu sair do jogo. Até mais!");
          break;
        } else if (digitada.toUpperCase().equals(original)) {
          System.out.println("Você acertou a palavra \"" + original + "\" em menos de 15 segundos. Parabéns!");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Você errou. A palavra certa seria \"" + original + "\".");
        }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Embaralhar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

  private String escolherPalavraAleatoria() {
    return this.palavras[(int) (Math.random() * this.palavras.length)];
  }

  private String embaralhar(String palavra) {
    List<Character> letras = new ArrayList<>();

    palavra.chars()
            .mapToObj(x -> (char) x)
            .forEach(letras::add);

    Collections.shuffle(letras);

    return letras.stream()
            .map(e -> e.toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
  }
}
```

Esta implementação leva em consideração a classe `TimedScanner` proposta [neste tópico de fórum](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/threads/13075-get-java-input-timer.html):

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class TimedScanner {

  private final Scanner in;

  public TimedScanner(InputStream input) {
    in = new Scanner(input);
  }

  private final ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor((Runnable r) -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t;
  });

  public String nextLine(int timeout) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Future<String> result = ex.submit(new Worker());
    try {
      return result.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private class Worker implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
      return in.nextLine();
    }
  }
}
```

No código proposto:

- Um `array` de `String` é criado com todas as palavras possíveis;
- O método `Math.random` é utilizado para escolher uma palavra aleatória do `array`;
- A palavra original é armazenada na variável `original`;
- Esta palavra é transformada em uma lista e embaralhada utilizando o método `Collections.shuffle`. Logo após isso o resultado é transformado novamente em uma `String`;
- A classe `TimedScanner` recebe a instrução por meio do método `nextLine` para aguardar a entrada de dados;
- A variável `digitada` é preenchida com a entrada do usuário e depois é verificada. Caso seja `null` significa que o usuário demorou mais de 15 segundos para informar a palavra. Caso seja `SAIR` o `looping` do jogo irá parar e o programa será finalizado. Caso seja igual a palavra escolhida ou caso o usuário erre a palavra uma mensagem será mostrada.